# UPDATE all rows of a single column using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 18 columns and I want to update all rows of the column page_count using LOAD DATA INFILE.  The file with the data is extremely simple, just \n separated values.  I'm not trying to pull off anything impressive here; I just want to update the values in that one single column - about 3000 records.  The code I'm using is

```
 LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/sbfh_counter_restore' REPLACE INTO TABLE obits FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (page_count);
```

And all this does is add one new row with the entire contents of the file dumped into the column page_count.  What am I doing wrong?  Shoud I use phpmyadmin?  I'd be happy to use that as it better fits my skill set ;)

I created the file using `SELECT page_count FROM obits INTO outfile '/tmp/sbfh_counter_restore'`

Comment: Obviously, there is a problem with carriage returns. Try to change '\r\n' for '\n' as on Linux it's only LF (not CR+LF as in Win). Verify your outfile format too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based what I can understand from MySQL document, it does not support loading data into ONE COLUMN, but it will require ALL COLUMNS to be present in the file in correct order.
At least, you should use SELECT * FROM obits INTO outfile, then load it back as it will ensure the column order is consistent.

As all your file content was loaded into a new row, I think you should check the primary key (or unique key) of your table. The rows will be matched by the key and update or insert based on the matching result. It is likely that page_count is not your primary or unique key.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I was going about it the wrong way.  I had to create a new table from a backup that had the correct data in page_count and then copied only that column into the production table using `update obits inner join temp_obits on temp_obits.obit_id  = obits.obit_id set obits.page_count = temp_obits.page_count;`